# How to train shape predictor dlib

Tags: python, dlib, facial-identification

can you help me? i want to know how to train the shape predictor from dlib. And i got this site http://dlib.net/train_shape_predictor.py.html i've download the predictor

But, i still don't understand it

```
 if len(sys.argv) != 2:
print(
    "Give the path to the examples/faces directory as the argument to this "
    "program. For example, if you are in the python_examples folder then "
    "execute this program by running:\n"
    "    ./train_shape_predictor.py ../examples/faces")
exit()
```

faces_folder = sys.argv[1]

what is the argument means? where i have to put the predictor?? i'm a newbie programmer so please, explain it to me how.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You are kind of giving the answer inside the example code you provided yourself. The python script is to be run from a console window. So open a console, navigate to the folder the script is in and execute the given command: `./train_shape_predictor.py ../examples/faces`.

If you have your training set in a different folder, you would have to replace the `../examples/faces` part with the appropriate path.

Regarding your question *what the argument means*: When you execute

```
./train_shape_predictor.py ../examples/faces
```

then `argv[0]` is `./train_shape_predictor.py` and `argv[1]` would be `../examples/faces`. This way you can pass information to a python script, when you run it from console.